# maven: plugin in repository but mvn doesn't find it

Tags: maven, nexus

Very strange thing:

we use a nexus repository and when I declare

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It get's downloaded into the repository:

```
Downloading: https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/groups/public-thirdparty/com/oracle/weblogic/wls-maven-plugin/12.1.3.0/wls-maven-plugin-12.1.3.0.pom
Downloaded: https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/groups/public-thirdparty/com/oracle/weblogic/wls-maven-plugin/12.1.3.0/wls-maven-plugin-12.1.3.0.pom (474 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/groups/public-thirdparty/com/oracle/weblogic/wls-maven-plugin/12.1.3.0/wls-maven-plugin-12.1.3.0.jar
Downloaded: https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/groups/public-thirdparty/com/oracle/weblogic/wls-maven-plugin/12.1.3.0/wls-maven-plugin-12.1.3.0.jar (146 KB at 557.8 KB/sec)
```

(and actually is present) but when I try to use it as plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wls-appc</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>appc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactLocation>com.oracle.weblogic:wls-dev:zip:12.1.3.0</artifactLocation>
                        <middlewareHome>${env.BEA_HOME}</middlewareHome>
                        <classpath>${util.classpath}</classpath>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

suddenly it doesn't find it anymore:

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:jar:12.1.3.0 in https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

note: it downloads it from a different repository compared to the one where it doesn't find it:

```
https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/groups/public-thirdparty
```

vs

```
https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/repositories/public
```

but it's locally there...

can anyone help out?

I'm really puzzled about this one...

if additional info is needed I'll be glad to provide it...

Comment: Have you tried removing your local repository? Sometimes the local repository gets into inconsistent state.

Comment: didn't work, if I disable the plugin it "builds" succesfully, if I enable it it fails...

Comment: Enable debug logging (`-X`), might give you a clue.

Comment: Debug the build with -X -e options. There must be something else, too.

Comment: thanks :) I will try and update the question if something isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was the issue:

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>external:*,!digit</mirrorOf>
    <url>https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
</mirror>

<mirror>
    <id>digit</id>
    <mirrorOf>digit</mirrorOf>
    <url>https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/groups/public-thirdparty/</url>
</mirror>
```

In settings.xml...

If you point to a "groups" -> "https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/**groups**/public-thirdparty/" (in our configuration) it does download the plugin, but it tries to verify it with only repositories (so https://my.secret.domain/nexus/content/**repositories**/public) and doesn't find it...

-X was indeed helpful in this...